# geowebcache-diskquota.xml is not read by geowebcache

Tags: geowebcache

I am using the stand-alone version of geowebcache instead of the geoserver-integrated one.
I wish to set a quota for the amount of space the cache may fill. I have created a geowebcache-diskquota.xml.
Unfortunately the quota does not seem to be enforced. No files seem to be deleted during use and the cache seems to be growing instead of settling at a stable number of files and diskspace.
The documentation was not quite clear on where the geowebcache-diskquota.xml should be placed.

I tried several locations such as the cache of the layer, the diskquota_page_store folder, but also in the WEB-INF and classes folders beneath tomcat.

Can someone please tell me what the exact location is for the geowebcache-diskquota.xml file or whether I should explictly enable diskquotas somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this so that maybe someone else has some use for it.
First of all the geowebcache-diskquota.xml should be located in the folder which stores all your caches. The documentation mentions something about that the application should generate one for you, but it does not.

The reason why I thought the geowebcache-diskquota.xml wasn't loaded by the application was because nothing happened with the cache. I found out it tried to empty the cache but returned an error message:

> 23 Nov 10:39:51 DEBUG [diskquota.CacheCleaner] - Expiring tile page TilePage[somelayer#EPSG:4326#image/jpeg@1,0,1] based on the global LFU expiration policy
>   23 Nov 10:39:51 WARN [diskquota.CacheCleanerTask] - Exception expiring tiles for [somelayer, someotherlayer]

followed by a java.lang.NullPointerException.

For the 'somelayer' layer I had removed the 4326 grid set and added another. After adding the 4326 gridset to 'somelayer' again everything worked and the cache was cleared.

Comment: Glad you solved your own problem :)